# Android check action in intent and do some logic

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, intentfilter

I set two intent filters in one activity.
`

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data  android:scheme="https://dou.ua/lenta/" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter> `
```

And check try to check action in creating activity.

```
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals("android.intent.action.VIEW ")) {

    } else {
      getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
      isDisplayingHomeBtn();
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.container, new FeedFragment())
          .commit();
    }
  }
```

**but i have a NullPointerException**

> Process: com.bogdan_kolomiets_1996.bogdan.dou_feed, PID: 5237
>                                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.bogdan_kolomiets_1996.bogdan.dou_feed/com.bogdan_kolomiets_1996.bogdan.dou_feed.ui.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2622)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:179)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1540)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5795)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1005)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:800)
>                                                                                                at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
>                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                                at
>   com.bogdan_kolomiets_1996.bogdan.dou_feed.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
>                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6071)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:179) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1540) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5795) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, that your activity placed here 'com.bogdan_kolomiets_1996.bogdan.dou_feed/com.bogdan_kolomiets_1996.bogdan.dou_feed.ui.MainActivity'?

This error ocured when you try to start your activity, not when you try to get an action.

Comment: OMG. you are right. This good worked, but when i add second intentfilter to activity place changed. Thank you))

Comment: You are welcome =) Please, don't forget check this message as an answer)